# Difference between path = path + [node1], path += [node1] and path.append(node1)

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, path, set

I am trying to figure out what the difference is between

1. path = path + [node1]
2. path += [node1]
3. path.append(node1)

I am getting the right path for path = path + [node1] but not the other two.

```
def find_path(self, node1, node2, path = []):
    """ Finds any path from node1 to node2 which may not be the shortest """

    path = path + [node1]
    if node1 == node2:
        return path
    if node1 not in self._graph:
        return None
    for node in self._graph[node1]:
        if node not in path:
            new_path = self.find_path(node, node2, path)
            if new_path:
                return new_path
    return None
```

Comment: What are the nodes? And do you get an error message or incorrect result?

Comment: They are just characters like 'A' and 'B' from [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F'), ('F', 'C')].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be *very* careful when using mutable default arguments. Please see [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

The reason for the difference in behaviour is that

```
path = path + [node1]
```

creates a new list and binds it to the name `path`. The other 2 alternatives modify the existing list bound to `path`.

---

As the linked question explains, default arguments are created when the function definition is compiled, *not* when the function is called. This is especially significant when using a mutable default arg in a recursive function because it implies that the default arg is *not* reset on each top-level recursive call.

If you don't want the "special" behaviour that using a mutable default arg gives you, you can do something like:

```
def find_path(self, node1, node2, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    # rest of code
```

If `None` is a valid arg for `path` then you'll need to use some other sentinel, eg

```
sentinel = object()
def find_path(self, node1, node2, path=sentinel):
    if path is sentinel:
        path = []
    # rest of code
```

---

Here's a short demo that illustrates the "special" behaviour of a mutable default arg. You can see that `lst` remembers its previous contents.

```
def test(a, lst=[]):
    lst += [a]
    print(a, lst)

for i in range(5):
    test(i)
```

**output**

```
0 [0]
1 [0, 1]
2 [0, 1, 2]
3 [0, 1, 2, 3]
4 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In contrast, using `lst = lst + [a]`, we create a new list rather than appending to the default list.

```
def test(a, lst=[]):
    lst = lst + [a]
    print(a, lst)

for i in range(5):
    test(i)
```

**output**

```
0 [0]
1 [1]
2 [2]
3 [3]
4 [4]
```

Comment: That explains it pretty well, thanks so much! So the path there is local while the path for the other two is global in the sense that they affect the previous recursion calls?

Comment: @SandeepChowdary> it's just that with python, if using a mutable object such as `[]` as default argument, it is created once at the beginning of your program and then re-used over and over again. Thus subsequent calls will see whatever modifications previous calls made to it. It is controversial design, as it goes opposite of most other languages, ending up being a recurrent trap for python beginners (and some more experienced devs as well)

Comment: Thanks guys that explains it so well!